# Trying startapp in Django and i get core exception update sqlite3

Tags: python, django, linux, bash, sqlite

When starting project in Django no sqlite3 file created. Trying startapp i get core exception update sqlite3 later version required. How update?

Comment: The error is not about the `sqlite3` *file*, but the `sqlite3` *package*.

Comment: i realize, but how update in linux?

Comment: i am not strong in terminal commands and have no idea(

Comment: Also i cannot runserver becouse of old version of sqlite

Comment: Rescue me please:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69885890/17632159). If you can provide us with more detail of the error, people can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: We need a [mcve] please.